# How to share my app?

Tags: android

I made an app in **Android Studio** and I built it and developed an apk which is stored in debug folder so I copied that apk in my phone and installed it ,it is working good in my phone  and  I am able to share it too ..I tried through **Xender** and tried to install it on my friend's phone ,app was installed but it was not working..can anyone help me with this..Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.spaceotechnologies.com/how-to-publish-android-app-play-store/   https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-publish-an-Android-app-free-in-the-Google-Play-store

Comment: Android is owned by google so google play is the most visible place to publish however you could put it on your own website or anywhere. If you gmail it to your friend or customers they can install an attached apk that way. You may want to minify and you do need to sign it instead of using the debug certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate **Build** apk file go `tool->Build Apk`.

Answer (score 0):

Different phones have often different APIs. Different APIs mean different parts of code (deprecated code, new code,...). So you should perform your code for most of APIs. You have to take your friends' mobiles, connect them to your computer and see the logcat.